# How to check if network traffic on a specific port is secured/encrypted

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, ssl-certificate, elasticsearch

We are running Elasticsearch 5.5.1 on Windows 2008 R2. We have installed Searchguard SSL plugin to enable SSL on Elasticsearch's transport port(9300) and are using jks certificate provided by our admin. How do I verify that the communication on this port is using SSL? Are there any inbuilt tools or other freeware tools that can be used to determine/monitor this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command to examine if the port is secured:
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect hostname:port

Alternatively:

you can use "Keystore Explorer" tool and select Examine> ExamineSSL, and put in your host and port and click OK,  if this port on that server is encrypted then it will show the certificate details that the port is using to encrypt data.

If the port is not secured, then it will show a message "Could not examine SSL certificates for (hostname:port) mentioned"